# How to use ajax for php in the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello friends i want use ajax on same php page. But problem is i can use ajax on   different pages but not in same page. I saw people accomplished it with jquery but i dont wanna use jquery. Thanks-

```
<?php 
    $gg =  $_POST['day'];
    echo 'today is '.$gg;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function clickMe(){
                // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
                var url = "example.php";

                var dayName = document.getElementById("dayName").innerText;
                var vars = "day="+dayName;
                req.open("POST", url, true);
                // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
                req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
                req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    let return_data = req.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
                }
            }
            // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
            req.send(vars); // Actually execute the request

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
        <p id="dayName">saturday</p>
        <button onclick="clickMe()">btn</button>
        <br><br>

        <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in your php code you are getting input via `$_GET` and in your code you are sending a POST request which is counter intuitive. What you can do is when certain parameters are passed either through query string or request body with a post request, you can write your desired output and call `die()` to not display the rest of it which will interfere with the response you get. I don't see a real reason to do so in the same file but, here's an example using query string:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['day'])) {
    die('Today is ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['day']));
}

?>
```

Then in your javascript code make sure you send a valid request according to your needs.

Comment: why `$_GET` ?? ?

Comment: sorrry i used $_GET .. i corrected it with $_POST.  now what i do? im kinda newbie so please dont mind

Comment: The `$_GET` is just for the example, as mentioned just before the example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use the same page to print html and do some php stuff. But, if you really want to do so, with javascript you can send another var like `ajax=1` and change you php code :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
    echo 'today is '.$_POST['day'];
    exit;
}
?>
```